# Cloud Build -> Google Cloud Storage: Question about downtimes at deployment time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build

```
- name: 'google/cloud-sdk:alpine'
  entrypoint: 'gsutil'
  args: ['-m', 'rsync', '-r', '-d', '-p', 'dist/', 'gs://my-site-frontend']
```

Good morning, the snippet above is the command that, via Google Cloud Build, copies the build of my VueJS frontend to a Google Cloud Storage bucket, where the website will be hosted.

My question is simple and short: **If any user is browsing at the time of this deployment (the execution of the command above), will he notice any inconsistencies, downtime or something like that when Cloud Build is copying/syncing the new files via rsync?** Is this task seamless enough? Maybe the user can feel some inconsistence when accessing some file that is being copied? Should I use Cloud Run instead?

Comment: If you are static hosting the website, you can create a new bucket every time you deploy and at the end change the DNS to point to the new website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have inconsistency for a while (files outdated or not found). The best solution is to use a product that package in a consistent manner the sources. You can use Cloud Run, but you can also use App Engine standard for that.

The main advantage of this 2 solutions is that each version is unitary, package in the same container. Like that, you can easily perform rollback, traffic splitting, canary release, A/B testing,.... All these things are impossible with Cloud Storage.

Comment: Thanks again. You are always very helpful. :)

I will use Cloud Run then.

Comment: Could Cloud CDN or some other strategy help someone deploying a VueJS frontend to a Cloud Storage bucket without suffering from these temporary inconsistencies at deployment time?

Comment: Cloud CDN or other caching strategy can help you, or kill you! Indeed, if all the file are cached in the same time, it can help you. If file aren't loaded in the same time, for example with an interval of 1 minute each, the CDN will create the inconsistency by serving files outdated and unconsistent. If  you use CDN, invalidate the cache after your deployment.

Comment: Thanks, so I will be fine with deployment time inconsistencies (404'd or outdated files) if I use Cloud CDN and invalidate it after each deployment? The files would always be accessed from the CDN and never (directly) from the bucket? Also, what deployment pipeline/strategy to Cloud Storage with Cloud Build would you recommend so that I can rollback to the previous build? Object versioning seems unflexible to project-level rollbacks.

Comment: GCS isn't a good candidate for easy rollback. The easiest way is to backup the files of the current revision in another path in GCS and overwrite them in the current one with the new version.