# gsutil cp creates nested directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build, gsutil

I’m trying to copy a folder (`/data/out`) from Cloud Build to Google Cloud Storage:

```yaml
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim'
    volumes:
      - name: 'vol1'
        path: '/data'
    entrypoint: 'gsutil'
    args:
      - -m
      - cp
      - -r
      - /data/out
      - gs://mybucket/files
```

When running this the first time, all the content from /data/out is copied to the bucket, which is what I wanted.

When I run it a second time to overwrite/update the files, there’s a folder `/files/out` instead, so the new files are in `mybucket/files/out/*` instead of `mybucket/files/*`.

How can I fix this?

I tried to add another step to remove the folder before copying it again (`rm -r gs://mybucket/files`), but this step fails the first time, as the folder does not exist yet, causing the build to fail/stop entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this to work with `rsync` instead of `cp` thanks to [Cloud Build -> Google Cloud Storage: Question about downtimes at deployment time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67304543)

```yaml
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim'
    id: copy
    volumes:
      - name: 'vol1'
        path: '/data'
    entrypoint: 'gsutil'
    args:
      - -m
      - rsync
      - -r
      - -d
      - /data/out/
      - gs://mybucket/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied a local folder generated in a previous step to a GS bucket. subsequently builds ran and overwrite the files.

I used:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
  args: [ 'cp', '-r',
            './public',
            'gs://{BUCKET_NAME}/test' ]
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Creates a nested `out/` folder with the files in it, instead of copying directly.